# Is there an easy way to produce a number from a set of bytes when leading bits are ignored from each byte?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, id3, arraybuffer

I'm attempting to produce a number from a set of bytes with JavaScript in Google Chrome, from an [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays/ArrayBuffer) to get at MP3 tag information. The ID3v2 specification [states](http://www.id3.org/id3v2.3.0#head-697d09c50ed7fa96fb66c6b0a9d93585e2652b0b) that to get the tag size you must take 4 bytes at a certain location and get the integer value from them, except:

> The ID3v2 tag size is encoded with
>   four bytes where the most significant
>   bit (bit 7) is set to zero in every
>   byte, making a total of 28 bits. The
>   zeroed bits are ignored, so a 257
>   bytes long tag is represented as $00
>   00 02 01.

The naive way to do this seems to be to go through each byte and get the values for each bit and produce a new 4 byte values, produced from the 7 bits from the original 4 bytes such that say for example we have these 4 original bytes:

```
0111 1111 0111 1111 0111 1111 0111 1111
```

I create a new ArrayBuffer and loop through each bit to produce:

```
0000 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

And then I calculate the integer value from this 32bit integer using [Uint32Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays/Uint32Array)

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Why not just approach it as interpreting a 4-digit number expressed in base 128 notation?  Multiply the high byte value by 2097152, the next by 16384, the next by 128, and then add those products to the value of the last byte.

Comment: Let me think about it, but why post your answer as a comment and not an actual answer?

Comment: I think that's a much better solution. I wish I pick/could vote up your uh answer.

Comment: I was in the middle of fixing breakfast for one of my kids and I didn't have time to type in a big complete answer :-)  I'll do it now ...

Comment: Why are you checking stack overflow when you're fixing breakfast for your kids? :P (I'm glad you answered).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think about it, what you've got is a 4-digit base-128 number.  Each of the bytes holds a single "digit", and each "digit" is a value between 0 and 127 (inclusive).  Thus, to turn them into a usable number, you just multiply and add like you'd do with any other base: the least-significant "digit" is the "one's place" digit, the next one is the "128s", the next is the "16384s", and the most-significant digit is the "2097152s" place.

I'm not sure exactly how to show this in code because I'm not really familiar with the new "ArrayBuffer" APIs; you use a "ArrayBufferView" or something to get access to the values, right?  Well assuming it's easy to get the individual bytes, it should be a very simple function to do the multiplies and additions.

Comment: Yep that worked perfectly. `header = new Uint8Array(data, 0, 10);` and then `tagSize = header[6] * Math.pow(128, 3);  tagSize += header[7] * Math.pow(128, 2);` etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you just target Chrome, you can also use DataViews to read out different datatypes of your bytestream: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays/DataView

Comment: That is pretty awesome. Thank you. :)